# Errors in installing angularx-social-login

Tags: angular

I'm new in using Angular and I encounter this problem when I tried install the `angularx-social-login` package on a project where I'm working on.

I got the errors bellow while trying to install `npm install --save angularx-social-login`.

Follows the errors:

> C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FrontEnd>npm install --save
>   angularx-social-login npm WARN @angular/animations@6.1.3 requires a
>   peer of @angular/core@6.1.3 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.2.0
>   requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.2.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.2.0
>   requires a peer of @angular/forms@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.7
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/compiler@^6.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a
>   peer of @angular/core@^6.0.7 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0
>   requires a peer of @angular/forms@^6.0.7 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@^6.0.7
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.7 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.7 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @ng-forms/file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/router@^6.0.7
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@^2.4.9 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^2.4.9 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.1
>   requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.4.9 || ^4.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.0-rc.2
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN ng-circle-progress@1.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.1.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN ngx-snackbar@1.2.0-rc.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN ngx-snackbar@1.2.0-rc.2 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN patternfly-ng@4.5.1 requires a peer of
>   typescript@^2.9.2 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN patternfly-ng@4.5.1 requires a peer of
>   rxjs@^6.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself. npm WARN angularx-social-login@1.2.5 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FrontEnd\node_modules.staging\fsevents-300da7c0\node_modules\abbrev'
>   -> 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FrontEnd\node_modules.staging\abbrev-edca6c5f'
>
> npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found: flatmap-stream@0.1.2
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-28T21_08_59_644Z-debug.log

Comment: Don't post text as an image, post it as text.

Answer (score 1):

`flatmap-stream` is a [malicious package](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/737) (the full story [here](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116)) and has been removed from npm (hence the 404). You should see what package depends on `flatmap-stream`and lock to a version that fixes that dependency (most have released a fix by now).

One can check what package uses flatmap using `npm ls flatmap-stream`

It's very often `event-stream` (which is now maintained by the npm team themselves) that fixes it [in version `3.3.4`](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1211).

Comment: so you mean i should use event-stream to fix the flatmap-stream

Comment: I observed the project was written on angular 6 before i picked it up and my own angular version is 7, i suspected the package is not installing because the package is written on Angular 6 while my own Angular Version is 7. Is there any suggestion of how to downgrade my Angular to 6 rather than 7 that is not accepting the installation of the social login package.

Comment: @AbioyeBabatunde not at all. i'm saying you should update whatever package you use that depends on flat-stream to a patched version (if it exists) or remove the dependency alltogether. And your 404 definitely come from the somewhat recent flatmap debacle rather than upgrading to Angular 7

Comment: Altho angular 7 might be the one introducing the dependency idk

Comment: so is it possible to go bck from Angular 7 to Angular 6. The package can only work with Angular 6 i think.

Comment: i wouldn't advise this. fix your dependencies instead.

Comment: check what package uses flatmap using `npm ls flatmap-stream` (also upvotes comments and answer plz?)

Comment: Thanks Mathieu K. I checked and it gave me the following feedback         

C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FrontEnd>npm ls flatmap-stream
sancoj@0.0.0 C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FrontEnd
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY save@2.3.2
  `-- UNMET DEPENDENCY event-stream@3.3.6
    `-- UNMET DEPENDENCY flatmap-stream@0.1.2

npm ERR! missing: save@2.3.2, required by sancoj@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: event-stream@3.3.6, required by save@2.3.2
npm ERR! missing: flatmap-stream@0.1.2, required by event-stream@3.3.6

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by doing this:

```
npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login

import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from '@abacritt/angularx-social-login';
```

Answer (score 0):

First install yarn `npm install -g yarn`

then instal angularx-social-login from yarn `yarn add angularx-social-login`